# Kendo IntegerTextBoxFor select all numbers on focus

Tags: selection, kendo-asp.net-mvc, onfocus

I've seen many great posts on using jQuery to select all text for regular input boxes...

```
$("input[type='text']").on("click", function () {
   $(this).select();
});
```

The above works great for

```
  @Html.TextBoxFor(...etc
```

But does not work for:

```
@Html.Kendo().IntegerTextBoxFor(...
```

and

```
 @Html.Kendo().CurrencyTextBoxFor(...
```

I tried to see if there's a focus event in Kendo I could attach to so I could select all, but no joy.

The funny thing is, the rendered input control does have type="text" so the jQuery input[type='text'] SHOULD work...but doesn't.

Anyone find something that works for these guys?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure if this will exactly work, but might get you started.

To do [much] with the Kendo rendered controls, you have to do something like:

```
var control = $('#my-control').data('kendoNumericTextBox');
```

Then you can call methods/properties on `control`.

So, in this case, something like this **might** work:

```
var control = $('#my-control').data('kendoNumericTextBox');
control.focus();
```

The API documentation for the NumericTextBox can be found here http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/web/numerictextbox#methods-focus

Comment: a similar post in the Telerik forums support your answer and extend it: function selectText(e) {
            $(e.container).find(".k-input.k-textbox").select();
            $('.k-input').on('focus', function () {
                var input = $(this);
                setTimeout(function () {
                    input.select();
                });
            });
        }